# Convert from binary to negabinary

Tags: code-golf, binary, base-conversion

Given a binary integer inclusively between `0` and `1111111111111111` (i.e. a 16-bit unsigned integer) as input, output the same integer in [negabinary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html).

The input can be in whatever format is most convenient for your language; for example, if it is easier for the program to handle input with 16 digits, like `0000000000000101`, rather than simply `101`, you can write the program to only accept input that way.

### Sample I/O

```
> 1
1
> 10
110
> 1010
11110
> 110111001111000
11011001110001000
> 1001001
1011001
```

Here is a [sample program](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225180424/https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25059665/BaseConverter.htm) I wrote that does base conversions, including negative and non-integer bases. You can use it to check your work.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit further, the input and output would have to be binary, right? I mean: character strings of `0`s and `1`s. Looks clear to me, but an answer makes me doubt lightly...

Comment: @M.Joanis The input is binary, the output is negabinary (which looks exactly the same as binary--a string of zeroes and ones--but the way the number is interpreted is different.)

Comment: The link appears to be down, which is a prime reason for why we require questions to be self-contained these days

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 21 characters

```
'01'[-(16/¯2)⊤-2⊥⍎¨⍞]
```

I used Dyalog APL for this, with `⎕IO` set to 0, allowing us to index arrays starting at 0 rather than 1.

Explanation, from right to left:

- `⍞` gives us the user's input as a character vector.
- `⍎¨` applies the execute function (`⍎`) to each (`¨`) of the aforementioned characters, resulting in a vector of integer 1's and 0's.
- `2⊥` decodes the vector from base 2 into decimal.
- `-` negates the resulting decimal integer.
- `(16/¯2)⊤` encodes the decimal integer into base `¯2` (negative 2). (`16/¯2` replicates `¯2`, `16` times, yielding 16 digits in our negabinary number.)
- `-` negates each element of our newly encoded number (before this, it consists of -1's and 0's), so that we can use it to index our character vector.
- `'01'[ ... ]` indexes the character array (`'01'`) using the 0's and 1's of the negated negabinary vector. This is so we get a prettier output.

Example:

```
      '01'[-(16/¯2)⊤-2⊥⍎¨⍞]
10111010001
0001101011010001
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <strike>32</strike> 31 characters

```ruby
m=43690
'%b'%(gets.to_i(2)+m^m)
```

Uses the [negabinary calculation shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#To_negabinary).

Comment: The input isnt hard coded. The 0xAAAA isnt the input, its the mask thats gonna transform the input. 0xAAAA is equivalent to 1010101010101010, which is used in a XOR operation to convert binary into negabinary.. The input itself comes from the `gets` keyword, which fetches from STDIN.

Comment: changed 0xAAAA to 43690 (which is the same number in decimal) to decrease character count by 1. Makes it harder to understand wtf is happening though.

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't ruby good so I wasn't sure. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, <strike>34</strike> <strike>29</strike> 27 characters

```
n*~]2base{.2%\(-2/.}do;]-1%
```

A plain straigt-forward approach. It is quite interesting that the shortest version is the one which first converts to number and then back to base -2 (at least the shortest version I could find up to now). But the nice thing about this one is, that it contains almost 15% `%`.

*Edit 1:* For base 2 we can save one modulo operation and also join both loops.

*Edit 2:* I found an even shorter code to convert binary string to integer.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>86</s> 83  Bytes

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Digits
c n|m<-0xAAAAAAAA=digits 2$xor(unDigits 2 n+m)m
```

Call using c and then an integer array for digits, e.g.

```
c [1,1]
```

PS: I'm new, did I submit this correctly?

EDIT: Saved some bytes thanks to Laikoni and also fixed some typos

EDIT2: Alternatively, c :: String -> String:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Digits
c n|m<-0xAAAAAAAA=concatMap show.digits 2$xor(unDigits 2(map(read.(:[]))n)+m)m
```

For 114 bytes (but you call it with a string: c "11")

Comment: Yes, you did! Welcome to the site! Hope you stick around!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can drop the parentheses around `undigits 2 n`, because the function application binds stronger than the `+m`. You can also save some bytes by binding `m` in a guard: `c n|m<-0xAAAAAAAA= ...`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (2.x), 77 characters

(not as short as the other solutions due to the need to manually switch base...)
Should satisfy the requirements.

```
i=input();d=""
while i:i,r=i//-2,i%-2;i+=r<0;d+=`r+[0,2][r<0]`
print d[::-1]
```

Suggestions for further improvements are welcome!

Feed it with starting values like this:
`0b1001001`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 68 bytes

```
function(b){for(r='',n=parseInt(b,2);r=(n&1)+r,n>>=1;n=-n);return r}
```

Would be 52 bytes in ES6, but that post-dates the challenge:

```
b=>eval(`for(r='',n=0b${b};r=(n&1)+r,n>>=1;n=-n);r`)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
Ḅb-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR0uSrtH///@jDXUMdQx0DHUgNIwFYRvEAgA)

Takes input, and produces output, as a list of digits.

### Explanation

```
Ḅb-2
Ḅ     Convert binary to integer
 b-2  Convert integer to base -2
```

This is pretty much just a direct translation of the specification.

Comment: I missed that. I'll put a note in the header.

Answer (score 1):

## k, 17 bytes <sub>noncompeting</sub>

Some of the features used probably postdate the challenge.

```
1_|2!{_.5+x%-2}\2/
```

Input is a list of 1's and 0's, and output is also a list of 1's and 0's.

[image: Examples of the program working.]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 69 Bytes

```php
for($i=bindec($argn);$i;$i+=$i%2&$c,$i>>=1,$c^=1)$r=($i%2).$r;echo$r;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7160ab7652db0829712bea72dd809bd7c4fdd1e7)

Answer (score 0):

## ES8, 54B

```
b=>eval`for(r='',n=0b${b};r=(n&1)+r,n>>=1;n=-n);r`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a binary string, output as a negabinary digit array.

```
Íì2n
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zewybg&input=IjEwMTAi)

Or, taking input as a binary digit array:

```
ì2JÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7DJKyQ&input=WzEsMCwxLDBd)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
C2(в
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2Ujjwqb//w0NDA0A)