# Negative base conversion

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

We already have a [base conversion question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69155/base-conversion-with-strings), but not one with negative bases (nope, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4447/convert-from-binary-to-negabinary) doesn't count).

([Corresponding wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base).)

You will receive a number (may be negative) and a base (must be negative), and your task is to convert the number into the base.

The base will only be from `-10` to `-2`.

#### Specs

- You may receive the number in any positive base, including unary.
- You may choose receive the magnitude of the base instead (`10` instead of `-10`).
- The input can be taken in any reasonable format.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest solution in bytes wins.

#### Testcases

```
input        output
8163, -10    12243
-8163, -10   9977
17, -3       212
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I could use Retina to do your linked challenge but I would not be able to trivially modify that algorithm to fit this challenge.

Comment: That may be true for Retina, but for most answers I can simply replace all `-2`s with `int(input)` and 2s with `-int(input)`

Answer (score 0):

### Jelly, 1 byte

```
b
```

Jelly supports negative bases with its base conversion builtin.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Yg&input=&args=ODE2Mw+LTEw)

(`bV` at two bytes if the output must be a single integer.)

Comment: Outputting a number as an array? Is that an accepted output format for numbers?

Comment: @Downgoat The challenge does not give a specific output format.

Comment: but an array of value [1,2,3] is not equivalent (or I don't think it can be) directly cast to the integer value of 123. If a challenge is to output a string. I wouldn't output a char array (unless that's a string in my language), I would output a string. See [this loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1789/40695)